# Google Sheets - Button to update Row

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers, google-sheets

I am not a big fan of some of the Stock Broker’s GUI, so I am attempting at tracking some of my assets on a Google Sheet.

**How can I create Manual (click a button) or Automatic triggers, based off of a certain date, to edit a cell's value or add a new entry into a new cell?**

Example Triggers:

```
1) Increment currently owned shares on the Dividend Payout Date.
2) Nightly/Weekly new entries for Profit/Loss for a company/set of companies.
```

Sample Sudo Logic:

1. When TODAY() == 2/2/2018(any variable date saved in a cell), update cell [current shares] with reinvested_shares + current_shares.
2. Create a new entry in next available cell with profit/loss for the day. New entry would be static and never changing. This could be a button to manually trigger or automatic.

Since you won't have the spreadsheet that contains the cell information, any sample template (with comments) would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: @Rubén I edited my post into a question, as I am not looking for someone to do it for me. I just have not found any help elsewhere on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After much trial and error, I was able to create a manual button to update and insert a new row into a sheet.

Example:

[image]

Goal is to copy/save the values of Row 2, create a new row underneath, and place the values into the newly created Row 3 without modifying any other values below.

Insert->Drawing->Shapes

Draw a Box, label it as "Update".

Tools->Script Editor

Paste/Save:

```
function updateInfo() 
{
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var stats_sheet = ss.getSheets()[1];
  stats_sheet.insertRowBefore(3);

  var todays_cells = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A2:D2").getValues();
  var update_todays_cells = stats_sheet.getRange("A3:D3");
  update_todays_cells.setValues(todays_cells);
}
```

Right-Click the Box, click the 3 dots, assign to script->"updateInfo" (without the quotes)

Clicking the button will result in this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you need to write a script for this.

The script loops through the data, checks the condition, updates the cell.

If you have a lot of cells to check, better to pull all the needed rows&columns as an array into the script, do the update of the array, and dump the array back to the spreadsheet. Much faster and probably prevents time outs.